# How to only allow specific layout states be used during gameplay

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, state

I'm using eclipse and I'm trying to figure out how to only allow a Portrait state be used during game play. I can't seem to find any options in eclipse to block the Landscape state.

I'd appreciate any assistance. I know it's probably a simple matter, but I can't seem to find it and I've not tried to do this before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to lock orientation for just one activity, or the whole application?

Comment: entire application would be preferred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest` file you can achieve this. You will add the `android:screenOrientation` tag in your application declaration. Something like this

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" > //HERE
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.SomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

You can change that to landscape as well. This attribute can also be applied to individual activities instead of the whole application if you need that.

Comment: I have 6 minutes to accept, but it looks like this works. Thanks!

Comment: I also appreciate the additional information on application via activity - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the activity tags of your manifest file, add this:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```